# Calendar Class in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to print `HOUR_OF_DAY,Minute and Second` using Calendar Class.
I used below command in my code.

```
  System.out.println(
      Calendar.HOUR+" "+
      Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY+" "+
      Calendar.MINUTE+" "+
      Calendar.SECOND+" "
      );
```

It Gives output as below:

```
10 11 12 13
```

Even when i ran this few hours back it gave same output.

I THOUGHT IT WILL PRINT CURRENT HOUR IN 24 HOUR FORMAT.But I am not getting that output.

So I want to know what this  **HOUR_OF_DAY**, **HOUR** are supposed to print.

Please clarify.

Comment: Before asking how something works, always check the documentation. It can not get any clearer than _that_...

Comment: i checked but did not understoood

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Calendar.HOUR`, `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` etc are just *constants* used to identify aspects of a date/time. They're typically used like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

I can't easily think of any situation in which you'd want to print out the constants themselves.

Now even if you were using that, you'd still then be converting `int` values to `String` values via string concatenation - that has no idea about what format you want, because you're not specifying it explicitly. There's no such thing as a "2-digit-format `int`"... an `int` is just a number.

You should look into `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` - that's the preferred way to format dates and times using the standard Java class libraries. (I'd personally encourage you to look into [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a far better date/time API as well, but that's a different matter.)

For example:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
// Prints the current time using 24-hour format
System.out.println(formatter.format(new Date());
```

Comment: We really need a "Beaten By Jon Skeet" badge on SO. You so frequently see other people complaining about being beaten by fractions of a minute to the same answer and think "get over it", but when it happens to you, you just feel ... I don't know, really amateur, I guess?

FYI: I think you answered this one within about 40 seconds of it being posted. That's intense.

Comment: @studro in fact, he answered the question 40 seconds _before_ it was asked.... It just took so long to appear here... Or maybe out of sportsmanship, he didn't post the answer before the question appeared on the site.

Comment: @studro - haha +1, you won the comments

Comment: @sturdo Jon's answers are already in SO database, including forthcoming ones, admins are only waiting for questions to be posted so that they provide the answers. ;)

Comment: Seems like Jon Skeet is RajniKant on SO.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println(
  cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+" "+
  cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+" "+
  cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+
  cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)+" "
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

What you did is you printed values of Calendar Constants.

Create instance of Calendar using `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`(this will create instance of calendar with current time and date having default timezone and default locale)

You can  print values of `HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR` using `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`, `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GregorianCalender (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html). This is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE and Calendar.SECOND are constants used to access fields within a Calendar object. You need to create a Calendar object first, and then use these constants to access its fields using the get() method.

Try [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for more information.

I've been beaten by Jon Skeet - his answer is pretty much perfect and is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
( GregorianCalendar ) myCal   // Cast from interface `Calendar` to concrete class `GregorianCalendar`.
.toZonedDateTime()            // Convert from troublesome old legacy class to modern java.time class.
.getHour()                    // Extract the hour of the time-of-day portion.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old `Calendar` class.

Assuming your `Calendar` is actually a `GregorianCalendar`, cast and convert. The old classes now have new methods to aid in converting to/from *java.time*.

`ZonedDateTime` is the *java.time* class replacing `GregorianCalendar`.

```
GregoriarCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCal ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Now interrogate for the parts you desire.

```
int hour   = zdt.getHour() ;
int minute = zdt.getMinute() ;
int second = zdt.getSecond() ;
int nano   = zdt.getNano() ;
```

Tip: You might want to extract a `LocalTime` object, to represent the time-of-day without date and without time zone.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).